# React on Rails with webpack on Heroku - CSS not used. - Works on local deployment

Tags: ruby, reactjs, heroku, webpack, deployment

I have an application that uses React as the front-end to rails on ruby. The React component is integrated to rails using webpack that now ships with rails.

Versions: 
React version 16.8
ruby-2.6.3
rails - 5.2.3
yarn v1.17.3

React css is not used. This applies toi both default.css and from the PrimeReact package.

The path locations are
app
  javascript
    css  - For deafult css
    img  - For back ground image referenced from css

PrimeReact is loaded via package.json

I have checked the cssLoader is in the dependencies and not devDependencies.

Please let me know how to activate CSS on the Heroku site as it works fine on MacBook.

Location of images
 app
  javascript
    img
     park3.jpg

package.json

```
{
 "name": "community-aid",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
 "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
 "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
 "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
 "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
 "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
 "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
 "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
 "actioncable": "^5.2.3",
 "axios": "^0.19.0",
 "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
 "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
 "classnames": "^2.2.6",
 "core-js": "^3",
 "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
 "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
 "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
 "eslint": "^6.1.0",
 "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
 "final-form": "^4.18.2",
 "jquery": "^3.4.1",
 "moment": "^2.24.0",
 "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
 "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
 "primereact": "^3.1.7",
 "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
 "react": "^16.8.6",
 "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
 "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
 "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
 "react-file-reader-input": "^2.0.0",
 "react-final-form": "^6.3.0",
 "react-final-form-html5-validation": "^1.0.3",
 "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
 "react-router": "^5.0.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
 "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
 "react-transition-group": "^4.2.1",
 "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
 "store": "^2.0.12",
 "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
 "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
 "webpack": "^4.0.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
},
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "jest": "^24.8.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
 },
"jest": {
 "roots": [
   "spec/javascript"
 ],
 "moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "app/javascript"
]
```

}
}

When I logon the heroku hosted application it should look and behave the same as the site on my macbook

Comment: Did you solve this? I have same issue

Comment: Yes, the solution is to have react code within a client subdirectory of the RoR stack. The script section on package.json should have a commend to start the react app.

Answer (score -1):

Running yarn init seems to resolved most of the issues so the question has has changed to simply CSS not loading. Editing the question to reflect.